# If a column is null, the other one should be filled (and vice-versa), in MySQL

Tags: mysql, validation

How can I validate this question?

If a column is null, the other one should be filled (and vice-versa), in MySQL.

Comment: The vice versa bit is problematic

Comment: Something like this?  `where ((columnA is null and columnB is not null) or (columnA is not null and columnB is null))...`

Comment: Yes, but where could I put this code to validate?

Answer (score 0):

I would normally handle this kind of problem at the application level rather than the database level, actually. I'm not currently aware of a good way to validate an either-or field set in MySQL. That said, you could go the route of a cronjob to check the data and update invalid rows, but that would be a passive rather than proactive solution, so I would still probably try to handle this in the application logic rather than in database constraints.

Comment: Every time it´s possible I prefer to deal with field values validation at database level, because I have to do it only once and if a fellow programmer forget about it the user will not be allowrd to make some mess in data. Because of it I´m looking for a db based solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a simple check constraint:

```
check (col1 is null and col2 is not null or col1 is not null and col2 is null)
```

Alas, although you can write this in MySQL, it does not get implemented.

The way to implement such a constraint (in MySQL) is using a trigger to validate the values on `insert` and `update`.

Comment: It´s not get implented? Wow... so I´ll do it by trigger.